# Symfony 3 doctrine migration bundle 1.2 "A non-numeric value encountered"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, doctrine-migrations

When i launch doctrine migration diff command from console I get this error (verbose mode):

```
cagliostro@cagliostro:~/Projects/Pherserk/my-project$ bin/console doc:mig:diff -vvv
[2016-12-04 13:30:03] php.DEBUG: mkdir(): File exists {"type":2,"file":"/home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle/Command/DoctrineCommand.php","line":35,"level":28928} 


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Warning: A non-numeric value encountered                   


Exception trace:
 () at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/Output.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleError() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/Output.php:145
 Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output->write() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/Output.php:134
 Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output->writeln() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DiffCommand.php:119
 Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand->execute() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle/Command/MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand.php:61
 Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\Command\MigrationsDiffDoctrineCommand->execute() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:254
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:837
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:187
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:118
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/cagliostro/Projects/Pherserk/my-project/bin/console:28

doctrine:migrations:diff [--editor-cmd [EDITOR-CMD]] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--filter-expression [FILTER-EXPRESSION]] [--formatted] [--line-length [LINE-LENGTH]] [--em [EM]] [--shard SHARD] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Is it a problem with any annotation or value in entities?
How can I debug it?

Comment: It seems to be that it happen when there are no migrations to generate or to execute. Symfony3 only.

Comment: That's a new warning added in PHP 7.1. Most likely it's a bug in Symfony.